# Replace multiple bytes in bytearray

Tags: python

How can I replace multiple bytes in a bytearray? For example:

```
b"\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"
```

I want to replace \x02\x03 with \xFF\xFF and \x04\x05 with \xEE\xEE. How can I do this all at once?

Comment: Do you know a priori the position of the bytes you need to remove? IN this case it is trivial, you just redefine the sub-array, say
`a[2:3] = ...`

Comment: No, I don't know where the offset of the bytes are, I have to search for them.

Comment: ok, then what about decoding them into a bytestring and then using the `replace`method?

Comment: Do it not all at once.

Answer (score 5):

The `replace` method can also be used on byte object in python

```py
a = b"\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"
b = a.replace(b"\x02\x03", b"\xFF\xFF").replace(b"\x04\x05", b"\xEE\xEE")
```

Comment: This is code is printing the 'E' and 'F' letters in lower case. Can u please align with case sensitive output ?

Comment: We are speaking of byte object `E` means `14` and `F` is  `15`. So there is no notion of case. You can write either `E` or `e` it will remain the exact same thing